# Restricting the url parameter values in Django URL

Tags: python, django, regex, django-urls, django-3.1

I have a Django web app that has 2 types of users, say customers, and business. I need to get the type of user trying to login. So I defined a url pattern as folows:

```
 path('login/<type>/', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
```

But how can I restrict the url patten to match only the following patterns

1. login/customers/
2. login/business/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use regex in the url. Something like...

```
url(r'^login/(?P<type>customers|business)', LoginView.as_view(), name='login')
```

Comment: if i proceed with the first option ..how can i get the parameter whether it is customer or business? and how can do the 2 nd method, that is what I really need

Comment: Hi thanks for accepting my answer. I deleted the first one as it may not work for your case. that type of solution works well for when you have opitonal_varialbe in the url. I left the regex one. just wanted to update you about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that in views.

```
if type not in ['customers', 'business']:
    messages.error(request, "Invalid Route')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('login')
```

PS: Do not use **type**. Its already defined in Python.

Comment: I actually need to know whether I can implement it with the url patterns

Comment: Oh ok. @ha-neul has answered it perfectly then.